# change sub-site master page in office 365 SharePoint?

Tags: office-365, master-page, sub-site

I want to change master page of my Office 365 SharePoint sub-site.

Can any one give me the exact solution, I am new to Office 365 SharePoint.

Comment: Do you want to create new MasterPage?

Comment: yes but , this is a subsite ! is it possible to create master page for sbsites ?

Comment: yes, you can create a MasterPage and that MasterPage you can assign to any of the Site/SubSite

Answer (score 1):

You can find the way for changing the MasterPage from [How to give a subsite a specific master page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144376/how-to-give-a-subsite-a-specific-master-page)

If the MasterPage option is missing under **Look and Feel** then you need to verify few things

- Your parent Site Collection must have **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** Feature activated from Site Collection Feature
- Your subsite must have **SharePoint Server Publishing** Feature activated

Let me know if you need more assist for this.

Comment: i cant activate SharePoint Server Publishing Feature, am getting error during activating this feature.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden Site scoped feature 'FeatureDefinition/15/dffaae84-60ee-413a-9600-1cf431cf0560' (ID: 'dffaae84-60ee-413a-9600-1cf431cf0560'). Hidden features cannot be auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden feature. Go Back To Site

Comment: am getting above error

Comment: I think you can get the solution of your above problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458627/super-complicated-enabling-the-publishing-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-in-the-new  Make sure you first activate your site collection feature and after site feature. let me know still you face any issue